# SQL - How to find a distinct value for specific parameters in sql where the data is in the same table

Tags: sql, database

I'm not sure what the easiest way is of accomplishing this with a SQL query

How do I find a unique value that is in column test = 1 but that value is not in any other value of test 2 or test 3. Meaning if there is dog B is in test 1 but also test 3 it would not show up in my results. I only want results that show up in test = 1 but they are unique to test = 1 and do not repeat anywhere else.

Using the example below my end result should only be Dog A as all the other values show up at least one more time. IE also I cannot just do a unique on the Dog Column as in test 4 z and y are unique.

I'm thinking two temp tables and then do a join but is there an easy way just from one query ?

```
   test dog
    1   a
    1   b
    1   c
    1   d
    1   e
    2   b
    2   c
    2   d
    2   e
    3   e
    3   b
    3   c
    4   z
    4   y
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using a subquery of the inverse parameters, I created a test table using the same data you have here and I got just 'a' but running this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dog FROM 2col 
WHERE test = 1 
AND dog NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT dog FROM 2col WHERE test != 1);
```

Comment: I think this may do it

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT #ensure we do not get duplicates
    test_one.dog
FROM
    dog_test test_one
    LEFT JOIN dog_test test_two ON test_one.dog = test_two = dog
                                   #don't join a record to itself
                                   AND test_one.test <> test_two.test 
WHERE
    test_one.test = 1
    AND test_two.test IS NULL #only get test_one records where there are no matching records
```

Comment: All the data is in one table

Comment: I know all the data is in one table, I only use one table and join it to itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to select all values that only have test = 1

```
select dog from mytable
group by dog
having count(case when test <> 1 then 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Show all unique combination of test and dog**

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/550a4/9 (MySQL)

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/718b2/2 (SQL Server)

```
select
  a.test, a.dog
from testing a
left join testing b on a.dog = b.dog
group by a.test, a.dog
having count(*) = 1
```

This query above will result in

```
test dog
1    a
4    x
4    y
```

How it works: Identical to how you were thinking of creating two temp tables, this SQL joins to itself on DOG. That means test=1,dog=b will join with test=2,dog=b and test=3,dog=c.

However, test=1,dog=a will join to only itself. Notice that test=1,dog=b will appear 3 times as it joins with test=2 and test=3 also. So, we group the data and count the number of times test/dog combination appears. If it appears once, that means it is a unique record.

**Show dog that uniquely appears for test 1**

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/550a4/10 (MySQL)

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/718b2/1 (SQL Server)

```
select
  a.test, a.dog
from testing a
left join testing b on a.dog = b.dog
where a.test = 1
group by a.test, a.dog
having count(*) = 1
```

This query above will result in

```
test dog
1    a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  T.test,
  T.dog
FROM
  myTable T
WHERE
  T.test = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
  SELECT
    * 
  FROM 
    myTable T2
  WHERE
    T2.dog = T.dog AND 
    T2.test <> 1
  )
```